# Updating plot arguments

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a slider that'll allow the user to adjust the alpha value for some grid lines I'm plotting, but it doesn't seem like the update function is working properly. The lines get darker with increasing alpha values, but they don't decrease with lower values. Any help is appreciated!

```
    axcolor = 'lightgoldenrodyellow'
    axalpha = plt.axes([0.2, 0.02, 0.65, 0.03], facecolor=axcolor)

    salpha = Slider(axalpha, 'Grid alpha', 0.0, 1, valinit=0.1)

    def update(val):
        aval = salpha.val
        g = ax.plot([grids[:,0], grids[:,2]], [grids[:,1], grids[:,3]], 
                     color='black', alpha=aval, label = "Grid lines")
    salpha.on_changed(update)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not updating the lines, but continuously plotting new lines on top of the old ones. In order to update a line create the line outside the updating function and use the updating function only to update the line.

```
g = ax.plot([grids[:,0], grids[:,2]], [grids[:,1], grids[:,3]], 
                     color='black', alpha=salpha.val, label = "Grid lines")
def update(val):
    for line in g:
        line.set_alpha(val)

salpha.on_changed(update)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. When I tried setting the plot function to (g,) I get an error that there's too many values to unpack (expected 1). When I used salpha.on_changed(g.set_alpha), I got an error that 'list' object has no attribute 'set_alpha'

Comment: Thats because you didn't provide a [mcve]. I still need to guess here, but the updated answer should now work for any possible case.

Comment: @jeffreyzhao If this answer works out, you should at least accept it if not upvoting it in the meantime. ImportanceOfBeingErnest is a real expert in `matplotlib`. His time spent on your question at least worth that.